# EventListener and retryable

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign, spring-retry

I would like to invoke some code after my application start. Is there any way to handle event:

```
Started SomeApp in 14.905 seconds (JVM running for 16.268)
```

I'm going to try if another application is up. I've tried to use Retryable but not its executed before application started and exception is thrown so application exits.

```
    @EventListener
    fun handleContextRefresh(event: ContextRefreshedEvent) {

        retryableInvokeConnection()
    }

    @Retryable(
        value = [RetryableException::class, ConnectionException::class],
        maxAttempts = 100000,
        backoff = Backoff(delay = 5)
    )
    private fun retryableInvokeConnection() {
    }

    @Recover
    private fun retryableInvokeConnectionExceptionHandler(ex: ConnectionException) {
    }
```

Maybe I should use PostConstruct and while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a `@Retryable` method within the same bean, it bypasses the proxy with the retry interceptor. Move the method to another bean and inject it.

The event is a better way than using `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: But how could I handle this after application is started. Not during startup process

Comment: nvm your sollution helped me and also I missed EnableRetry

Comment: may you know if there is possibility to specify in retryable retry until success

Comment: You have to create an external `interceptor` with an `AlwaysRetryPolicy`.